# Can you match any compound type with _Generic in C?

Tags: c, generics, macros

I would like to detect if the macro call is done on a struct type. A naive approach didn't work:

```
#define IS_STRUCT(x) _Generic((x), struct *: 1, default: 0);
```

as `_Generic` requires a **complete type** in the spec and `struct *` isn't one…

Is there any other working trick that would make selecting on *general* structures possible?

Comment: How would you expect to use this macro?  There may be a better way of accomplishing what you want.

Comment: @dbush: I want to use it in another macro that checks if a type (a variable type) is a pointer. I know that the current consensus is that this is not possible, however I'm rejecting it and looking for a solution :)

Comment: You mean something passed to a variadic function, i.e. using `va_arg`?  If so, you need to supply type information to the function in some way, for example `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: @dbush: No, I mean the regular pointer type, i.e.: I need an IS_POINTER(x) macro that would evaluate `int *` to 1 and `int` to 0, etc.

Comment: But how will you use that information?  This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What problem do you think knowing whether an identifier is a pointer (or struct pointer) will solve?

Comment: I would provide a frontend macro for my library function, which would work either with the argument in question being pointer, or not – the macro would prepend & in the second case. This is my fun goal of having such a convenient API functions… compatible/accepting both pointer and non-pointer type of the main argument.